# CognitiveServices.Speech Blazor Server not working when Published to Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor, text-to-speech

I am using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech in a Blazor Server App and I can convert Text to Speech and hear the voice while running the App in VS2019 on my PC but If I publish it to Azure I don't hear any sound, Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: Blazor Server executes on the *server*. You're trying to play sound on the *server's speakers*. The only reason you hear anything on your machine is because that's the server. I seriously doubt web servers have speakers, but if they did, some datacenter employee may have gotten a scare when a machine started speaking suddenly

Answer (score -1):

I test this service with an `asp.net core MVC project` converting text to speech, and got the same situation with you.

The void play automatically after converting locally, but not played on Portal. I check if the `.wav` file created or not in Kudu. It shows the file had been created, which means it's not a problem it didn't play, you could download it to listen.
[image]

By the way, I use the [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-csharp), just modify the path to store `.wav` file:

```
    public async Task SynthesisToSpeakerAsync(string text)
    {
        // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
        // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
        // The default language is "en-us".
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourServiceRegion");
        string path = string.Empty;
        string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "/MyMedia/";
        string filename = "sample.wav";
        // Try to create the directory.
        //DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(contentRootPath);
        // Creates a speech synthesizer using the default speaker as audio output.
        using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config))
        {
            // Receive a text from console input and synthesize it to speaker.
            Console.WriteLine("Type some text that you want to speak...");
            Console.Write("> ");

            using (var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text))
            {
                if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized to speaker for text [{text}]");
                    var stream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result);
                    await stream.SaveToWaveFileAsync(contentRootPath+filename);
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully saved");
                }
                else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                {
                    var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

                    if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Use this api to invoke:

```
public string test(string txt)
    {
        SynthesisToSpeakerAsync(txt);
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: You never await that method, so the method yields and the request terminates when the first `await` inside `SynthesisToSpeakerAsync` is encountered. The code never has a chance to return anything to the caller. Besides, what you try to do is play some sound *on the web server's speakers*.