# How can I capture audio in Blazor Server?

Tags: azure, blazor-server-side, azure-cognitive-services

My app:
https://vcat.azurewebsites.net/voice

uses azure voice to text service on a blazor server side. It works fine locally, but when published at azure it does not work.

What is wrong?

As I have understood it is not only me who has this problem. This is another one:
[CognitiveServices.Speech Blazor Server not working when Published to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65599466/cognitiveservices-speech-blazor-server-not-working-when-published-to-azure/73620623#73620623)

here is the code:

```
private async Task record()
    {
        try
        {
            _isRecording = true;

            _question = string.Empty;
            _answer = string.Empty;

            using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
            using var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(_speechConfig, audioConfig);

            var speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
            _question = speechRecognitionResult.Text;

            _isRecording = false;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_question))
            {
                _question = "Please try again!";
            }
            else
            {
                //_isThinking = true;
                await answer();
                //_isThinking = false;

                await speak();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error?.ProcessError(ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: The code you link to has some big bugs, like never awaiting for the ACS call to return.  If ACS was broken a lot of developers would have noticed anyway.

Comment: Blazor Server runs on the *server* and updates the browser UI. This means that, unless Blazor Server somehow redirects the browser's microphone,  `AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput()` is trying to use the VM's microphone. Which probably doesn't exist

Comment: So what should I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: If you read my question I say it works fine locally but not on azure after publishing. These guys have the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65599466/cognitiveservices-speech-blazor-server-not-working-when-published-to-azure/73620623#73620623

Comment: And the discussion on the Github issue you commented on clearly explains why, as I did. The answers in the issue explain the solution - use the Javascript SDK. The code you posted uses the *server's* microphone, not the browser's. On your local machine, that's your microphone. On a VM, there's no microphone. And even if there was, it would capture the data center's noise, not the browser's audio

Comment: As for "these guys" they don't have the same problem. They don't even execute their code, because they forget to `await` the async call. Even if that was fixed, they'd play the sound on the *server's* speakers, assuming there were any

Answer (score 1):

A very late answer but this might be what your looking for -> Audio Captured via JS Interop and transferred back to Blazor Server
[Record Audio In Blazor Server with wav format using Recorder.js](https://mbuotidem.github.io/posts/2020-12-24-record-audio-in-blazor-using-mediarecorder-api-and-recorderjs.html)

This is working fine for me.

Wish you all the best

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34621092)